# Some problems with generating the Mandelbrot set

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js, mandelbrot

I wrote a program on processing to generate the mandelbrot set and was successful but once i changed c to a constant complex number, I was unable to get any patterns with my program. I must be having a blind spot since I can't seem to debug my program. Can everyone please give me some advice? Thanks!

The lines commented out in the mand function is the the way I tried to change the value of c, but so far I've never been able to get any kind of pattern except for generating the Mandelbrot set.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background(200);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  loadPixels();
  for (let x=0; x<=width; x++) {
    for (let y=0; y<=height; y++) {
      a=map(x, 0, width, -2.5, 1);
      b=map(y, 0, height, -1, 1);
      z=new Complex(a, b);
      f = (mand(z))
      //i = map(f,1,100,0,255);
      pixels[(x+y*width)*4]=sqrt(f/100);
      pixels[(x+y*width)*4+1]=255;
      pixels[(x+y*width)*4+2]=150;

    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}

var Complex = function(a, b) {
  this.re=a;
  this.im=b;
  this.modSq=(a*a+b*b);
}

Complex.prototype.square = function() {
  a=sq(this.re)-sq(this.im);
  b=2*this.re*this.im;
  return new Complex(a, b);
}

function mand(c) {
  oldZ=new Complex(0, 0);
  for (let i=1; i<=100; i++) {
    newZ=oldZ.square();
    newZ.re+=c.re;
    newZ.im+=c.im;
    //newZ.re+= -0.70176;
    //newZ.im+= -0.3842;
    oldZ=newZ;
    if (oldZ.modSq>=4) {
      return i
    }
  }
  return 0
}
```

Comment: Right now the variation between colors of each pixel is imperceptible because the return value of mand() is either 1 or 0 so, in the end, the red value of the pixel can only be either 0 or 0.1. Is there any more code we're missing?

Comment: @Julian No. The result of `mad` is any number. Most of the numbers are in the range [0, 1].

Comment: The result of land is 0 to 100, which you then divide by 100 and then sqrt. Sri, final color is epithet 0 or 1

Comment: @Him Chan You're right! that's an **i**, I thought it was a **1**. The point still stands, though.

Answer (score 2):

The values for the color channels have to be in the range [0, 255]. The result `f` of the [Mandelbrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) fractal function is any number, most of the results are numbers below 1.0, but the function returns even very high numbers, too.
You have to map this values to a the colors of the pixel.

I recommend to calculate color values in the range [0.0, 1.0]:

```js
cR = Math.min(sqrt(f/100.0), 1);
cG = Math.min(sqrt(f/50.0), 1);
cB = Math.min(sqrt(f/10.0), 1);
```

Finaly map them to the range [0, 255]:

```js
pixels[(x+y*width)*4]   = cR * 255;
pixels[(x+y*width)*4+1] = cG * 255;
pixels[(x+y*width)*4+2] = cB * 255;
```

See the example, where I applied the changes to you original code:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    background(200);
    noLoop();
}

function draw() {
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    loadPixels();
    for (let x=0; x<=width; x++) {
        for (let y=0; y<=height; y++) {
            a=map(x, 0, width, -2.5, 1);
            b=map(y, 0, height, -1, 1);
            z=new Complex(a, b);
            f = (mand(z))
            //i = map(f,1,100,0,255);

            cR = Math.min(sqrt(f/100.0), 1);
            cG = Math.min(sqrt(f/50.0), 1);
            cB = Math.min(sqrt(f/10.0), 1);
            pixels[(x+y*width)*4]   = cR * 255;
            pixels[(x+y*width)*4+1] = cG * 255;
            pixels[(x+y*width)*4+2] = cB * 255; 
        }
    }
    updatePixels();
}

var Complex = function(a, b) {
    this.re=a;
    this.im=b;
    this.modSq=(a*a+b*b);
}

Complex.prototype.square = function() {
    a=sq(this.re)-sq(this.im);
    b=2*this.re*this.im;
    return new Complex(a, b);
}

function mand(c) {
    oldZ=new Complex(0, 0);
    for (let i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        newZ=oldZ.square();
        newZ.re+=c.re;
        newZ.im+=c.im;
        //newZ.re+= -0.70176;
        //newZ.im+= -0.3842;
        oldZ=newZ;
        if (oldZ.modSq>=4) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a good answer and covers specifically what is being asked. I think it is worth pointing out that in order to use the pixels array in situations with pixel density greater than one you will also have to account for more than 1 pixel at each x y coordinate. For example with a pixel density of 2 the above code will work correctly if we multiple height and width by 2.